# error 'Could not download' for Edge browser when installing selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium

Im trying to install Selenium Standalone for non-admin user/Windows/NodeJS  with command `selenium-standalone install`
bit it gives error:

> edge install: from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/2/342316D7-EBE0-4F10-ABA2-AE8E
>   0CDF36DD/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe to:
>   C:\Users\pkazim01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-standalone.sele
>   nium\edgedriver\15063-MicrosoftEdgeDriver.exe
>   C:\Users\pkazim01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-standalone\bin\selen
>   ium-standalone:111
>           throw err;
>           ^ Error: Could not download https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.5/IE
>   DriverServer_x64_3.5.1.zip: Error: unhandled critical extension
>       at Request. (C:\Users\pkazim01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\s

How to fix this Edge driver download?

Comment: download the latest exe from the URL and pass it in System.setProperty https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/2/342316D7-EBE0-4F10-ABA2-AE8E0CDF36DD/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe download it

Comment: how to fix it fully:)?